# Programmatically connect two subsystems

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I'm trying to build a complex model programmatically reusing some custom blocks/models I have developed before, but I cannot manage to connect two PMC_Port

This is what I have:

```
% Main system    
sys_name = 'model';
sys = new_system(sys_name)
open_system(sys_name)

load_system('circuit_cell') % Subsystem with 6 PMC_Port elements
                            % stored in circuit_cell.mdl file
% Add cell #1
add_block('built-in/Subsystem', [sys_name '/cell1'])
Simulink.BlockDiagram.copyContentsToSubSystem('circuit_cell', [sys_name '/cell1']);

% Add cell #2
add_block('built-in/Subsystem', [sys_name '/cell2'])
Simulink.BlockDiagram.copyContentsToSubSystem('circuit_cell', [sys_name '/cell2']);

% And now I want to connect one cell with the other
add_line('model', 'cell1/1', 'cell2/1', 'autorouting', 'on')
```

...but I always get a 'Invalid Simulink object name: cell1/1' error message.

EDIT.- Here it is circuit_cell.mdl file: http://pastebin.com/mXuVFtM3

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but I don't get any error. Can you provide the 'circuit_cell'? Does it have input and output ports?

Comment: I've edited the question to post a link to 'circuit_cell.mdl'. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to connect ports (maybe I'm misunderstanding what they were thought for)

Comment: If you go into `cell1` and select the (presumably output) block you want to connect to `cell2` with the mouse, then type `gcb` at the command line, what do you get? Is it really `cell1/1`? Likewise for for `cell2/1`.

Comment: @am304 Yes, checked that and names are ok: `cell1/1` and `cell2/1`; and if I change names I get the updated ones with `gcb` ...and it is failing the same way when calling `add_line` with them.

Comment: @jgsogo OK, if they are Simscape or physical ports, you may want to try something like `cell1/RConn1` (if on the right-hand side of the block) or `cell1/LConn1` (if on the left-hand side of the block). I have a vague memory that these blocks are special and the exact want to connect them programmatically is not documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @am304 comments I manage to *solve* this issue.

Connection through physical ports must be made through `RConn1` and `LConn1` keynames, so the command `add_line` should be executed as follows:

```
add_line('model', 'cell1/RConn1', 'cell2/LConn1', 'autorouting', 'on')
```

Tested for:

- Matlab Version 7.12.0.635 (R2011a)

Thanks!

Edit.- As @am304 says it's not documented so it can be changed. If more versions are checked, please post a comment and I will update the answer.

Comment: Note that this syntax may change in future releases, as all undocumented features.