# Generating sub-systems based on user input (MATLAB/SimMechanics)

Tags: matlab, simulink

The user in this webinar;

http://www.mathworks.com.au/videos/parameterizing-bodies-68850.html?form_seq=conf1134

can create new levels of links for the scissor lift by copy pasting the sub systems.

I was wondering if there was any way the number of subsystems and the joints could be automated via user input.

i.e a gui which allows the user to input the number of levels in the scissor lift and that number of levels (subsystems) is generated in SimMechanics.

If someone could provide a solution I could adapt it to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can automate it, as long as you know what susbsytems and what joints you want to add. The functions of interest are:

- [`add_block`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/add_block.html)`(path_to_your_subsystem,path_to_destination_subsystem)` (I assume your susbsystem is stored in a library). You probably want to specify the 'Position` parameter so that all blocks don't end up on top of each other. It will take some experimenting to find coordinates that work for your model and that are parameterised based on the number of susbystems to add.
- [`add_line`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html)`(path_to_subsystem_of_interest,path_to_output_port,path_to_input_port)`. You'll need to know which port you want to connect to which and figure out how many times you need to do this based on the number of subsystems to add. Simscape and SimMechanics are a special type of ports, and you need to refer to them correctly otherwise it won't work, see [Programatically connect two subsystems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793255/programatically-connect-two-subsystems) for more details (note: this is undocumented as far as I know and is therefore likely to change in a future release).

So in short, yes it's possible (I've done it in the past), but it's by no means easy. See [this blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2010/01/21/building-models-with-matlab-code/) for a very simple introduction.